# Yii2 After configuring httpd.conf, still appending the web folder in url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, yii2, httpd.conf

This is the set up of my httpd.conf to my yii application

```
Alias /attendance "C:/wamp/www/myproject/web"
<Directory "C:\wamp\www\myproject\web">
    # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
    RewriteEngine on
    # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php

    # ...other settings...
</Directory>
```

This works fine if I open up in browser

`http://localhost/attendance/`

but when I navigate to the page like about,contact,Login

it will use the `myproject` in the url like this

`http://localhost/myproject /web/site/about`

also as you can see that the web folder is appended in the url

how can I use my alias and remove the appended web in url

Answer (score 0):

Set `DocumentRoot` to your project path `"C:/wamp/www/myproject/web"`.